# Cryptic with some cross words

Tags: knowledge, cryptic-crosswords

> [image]
>
> **Across**
>   1. Philosopher rejects Vietnamese soup, producing gas (5)
>   3. A penguin's formal attire (3)
>   5. Primate's kiss is the greatest success (4)
>   7. Meet not in extreme Korean clothing (3)
>   10. Cat woman's counterpart with a cross (4)
>   11. Feline with spoken connections (4)
>   12. Weapon behind Norse god's chest (6)
>   14. Sheffield couple attracted to adult-rated video game, briefly (3)
>   16. Dynasty villain turns over six elaborate gems (6)
>   17. Allied opposition has large leaf properties (5)
>   18. In the middle of an agitated melee, embrace a grammar unit (6)
>   19. Sedative for Santa between crucifixes (5)
>   20. Cross the first street after heading to discriminator (6)
>   21. Chief axiom's secret copy sent by email (1-3)
>   24. Half-litre cognac makes a light snack (6)
>   28. Relax at sea to be less strict (5)
>   29. Headless snake in a heartless curse makes falsehood (4)
>   32. Genesis follower's emigration (6)
>   35. 29th Chinese president goes west, is double-crossed (4)
>   36. Female concealing Wade's adversary sabotaged copier (5)
>   37. Horse loses shadow to send a document (3)
>   39. Gas missing nitrogen, with oxidizing second component! (4)
>   40. Austrian range's last signs of weaponized disease (3)
>   41. Large single mother associated with a letter (4)
>   42. Seconds of extremely internationally essential name service (3)
>   43. Turn next to nothing to operating system (4)
>   44. Sussex English retreat reveals former lovers (4)
>
> **Down**
>   1. Typesetting engine either way (5)
>   2. Blow out former sleet audibly (6)
>   3. Drive down the runway, intently leading the charge at the front (4)
>   4. International body is formerly epicene (6)
>   5. A man with a smart device (5)
>   6. Darius and Xander are very small (4)
>   8. Watch an acting part by an unknown (5)
>   9. UK resident holds former EU drama (6)
>   10. Planck and Weber's thousand hatchets (5)
>   13. Clutching crucifix, Rachel's sister brings up physicist (5)
>   14. The last, not last, third-to-last hair loss medicine (5)
>   15. Caramel dessert gets back former colour (6)
>   20. Turn around hydra's head, multiply hybrid (6)
>   22. Oddly flag user experience as fake (4)
>   23. Pixar's choppy practical application (6)
>   25. Dresden native changes sides for island (5)
>   26. Head-scratching athlete makes a jump (4)
>   27. Essential to fix a robot coming up a compound (5)
>   30. Farm animals are second to none, times square closer north (4)
>   31. Letter closer's winning line (3)
>   32. Chromosome in the middle of one altered gene part (4)
>   33. Make chromosomes for antibiotic (4)
>   34. Sound effects getting around primary audio port (4)
>   38. Cut back a quintillion times (3)

Comment: (I see what you did there.)

Comment: Wordplay in 37a is backwards, no? [EDITED to add:] Yup, better now.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Oops, you're right. Fixed!

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan what? who?? where???

Comment: @OmegaKrypton All will be revealed when an actual answer is posted (or perhaps sooner). I'm maybe 70% done.

Comment: (I see Remi Henry is also on the case but haven't looked at his answers and have no idea how close he is.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan, well i'm trying to solve it while I have a few minutes of break at work, and i'm not so good, so for now I only have these 2 answers ^^'

Comment: Also at work, but maybe more shameless about solving at work. Nearly done now.

Comment: Should 38 be Cut UP rather than Cut Back?

Comment: @ChrisCudmore Cut up would make sense for sure. Is "back" not used for down clues? I thought the word can refer to vertical movement as well, e.g. "I dropped my ball but it bounced back".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> XENON    1. Philosopher rejects Vietnamese soup, producing gas (5)
> TUX      3. A penguin's formal attire (3)
> APEX     5. Primate's kiss is the greatest success (4)
> EXR      7. Meet not in extreme Korean clothing (3)
> MANX    10. Cat woman's counterpart with a cross (4)
> LYNX    11. Feline with spoken connections (4)
> THORAX  12. Weapon behind Norse god's chest (6)
> FFX     14. Sheffield couple attracted to adult-rated video game, briefly (3)
> ALEXIS  16. Dynasty villain turns over six elaborate gems (6)
> AXILS   17. Allied opposition has large leaf properties (5)
> LEXEME  18. In the middle of an agitated melee, embrace a grammar unit (6)
> XANAX   19. Sedative for Santa between crucifixes (5)
> SEXIST  20. Cross the first street after heading to discriminator (6)
> EFAX    21. Chief axiom's secret copy sent by email (1-3)
> PINTXO  24. Half-litre cognac makes a light snack (6)
> LAXER   28. Relax at sea to be less strict (5)
> HOAX    29. Headless snake in a heartless curse makes falsehood (4)
> EXODUS  32. Genesis follower's emigration (6)
> IXXX    35. 29th Chinese president goes west, is double-crossed (4)
> XEROX   36. Female concealing Wade's adversary sabotaged copier (5)
> FAX     37. Horse leaves shadow to send a document (3)
> NEOX    39. Gas missing nitrogen, with oxidizing second component! (4)
> RAX     40. Austrian range's last signs of weaponized disease (3)
> MAXI    41. Large single mother associated with a letter (4)
> XNS     42. Seconds of extremely internationally essential name service (3)
> UNIX    43. Turn next to nothing to operating system (4)
> EXES    44. Sussex English retreat reveals former lovers (4)
>
>
> XETEX    1. Typesetting engine either way (5)
> EXHALE   2. Blow out former sleet audibly (6)
> TAXI     3. Drive down the runway, intently leading the charge at the front (4)
> UNISEX   4. International body is formerly epicene (6)
> ALEXA    5. A man with a smart device (5)
> XXXS     6. Darius and Xander are very small (4)
> ROLEX    8. Watch an acting part by an unknown (5)
> BREXIT   9. UK resident holds former EU drama (6)
> MAXES   10. Planck and Weber's thousand hatchets (5)
> HAXEL   13. Clutching crucifix, Rachel's sister brings up physicist (5)
> FINAX   14. The last, not last, third-to-last hair loss medicine (5)
> FLAXEN  15. Caramel dessert gets back former colour (6)
> SPHINX  20. Turn around hydra's head, multiply hybrid (6)
> FAUX    22. Oddly flag user experience as fake (4)
> PRAXIS  23. Pixar's choppy practical application (6)
> NAXOS   25. Dresden native changes sides for island (5)
> OXER    26. Head-scratching athlete makes a jump (4)
> BORAX   27. Essential to fix a robot coming up a compound (5)
> OXEN    30. Farm animals are second to none, times square closer north (4)
> XXX     31. Letter closer's winning line (3)
> EXON    32. Chromosome in the middle of one altered gene part (4)
> DOXY    33. Make chromosomes for antibiotic (4)
> SFAX    34. Sound effects getting around primary audio port (4)
> AXE     38. Cut back a quintillion times (3)
>
> X E N O N T U X A P E X
> E X R B M A N X L Y N X
> T H O R A X I H E F F X
> E A L E X I S A X I L S
> X L E X E M E X A N A X
> S E X I S T X E F A X P
> P I N T X O B L A X E R
> H O A X E X O D U S N A
> I X X X X E R O X F A X
> N E O X O R A X M A X I
> X N S U N I X Y E X E S
> ```

I have to protest about

> the Roman numerals; 29 (or 29th) is XXIX, not IXXX.

I confess that I haven't actually checked all the things that look like brand names etc., but they all seem plausible at least :-).

The joke, of course, is

> that every answer has an X in it, so they are all *cross* words.

Comment: Wow, good job. I guess finding this "joke" helped to find some answers.

Comment: Argh, apparently I've forgotten how numbers work... Didn't even consider looking that up to be sure (facepalm)

Comment: @RémiHenry Yes, it was very helpful! (And it also made it possible to consider some things as possible answers that otherwise would have seemed just impossible.)

Comment: How did you parse 37 and 41 A?

Comment: 37 = SHADOWFAX-SHADOW = FAX (Shadowfax being a fictional horse, in _The Lord of the Rings_); I'm afraid my answer still contains the old version of that clue that had its wordplay the wrong way around, but OP's fixed it in the actual puzzle.

Comment: 41 has "large single" (drink or whatever) as def, and MA+XI as wordplay. [EDITED to add:] I see in comments to Chris's answer that in fact a different sort of single is in view; my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Good job to Gareth McCaughan.  I'm including this answer because I believe in supplying full parsing to a cryptic.

Common Cues in this puzzle

> X - Cross, times, multiply, adult (x-rated) gene (also XY) Female (XX)
>  EX - Late, Former

**Across**

1 Philosopher rejects Vietnamese soup, producing gas (5)

> **XENOphoN**

3 A penguin's formal attire (3)

> **TUX** (Linux Penguin)

5 Primate's kiss is the greatest success (4)

> **APE+X**

7 Meet not in extreme Korean clothing (3)

> **EXR** EXtReme (-m,e,e,t)  Korean clothing manufacturer.

10 Cat woman's counterpart with a cross (4)

> **MAN(X)**

11 Feline with spoken connections (4)

> **LYNX** LINKS homophone

12 Weapon behind Norse god's chest (6)

> **THOR(AX)**

14 Sheffield couple attracted to adult-rated video game, briefly (3)

> **FFX** Final Fantasy X

16 Dynasty villain turns over six elaborate gems (6)

> **ALEXIS** SIX ELAborate (turn over)

17 Allied opposition has large leaf properties (5)

> **AXI(L)S**

18 In the middle of an agitated melee, embrace a grammar unit (6)

> **LEXEME** Anagram (agitated) of MELEE + X (in the middle) ??? X is embrace ???

19 Sedative for Santa between crucifixes (5)

> **X+ANA+X** Santa ANA (California Winds)

20 Cross the first street after heading to discriminator (6)

> **SE + X + I + ST** Heading - StackExchange at top of this page. (First Street is I ST)

21 Chief axiom's secret copy sent by email (1-3)

> chi**EFAX**iom

24 Half-litre cognac makes a light snack (6)

> **PINT+XO** (similar to TAPAS)

28 Relax at sea to be less strict (5)

> **LAXER** Anagram (at sea) of RELAX

29 Headless snake in a heartless curse makes falsehood (4)

> **H(OA)X** b**OA** in **H**e**X**

32 Genesis follower's emigration (6)

> **EXODUS** (second book of the bible)

35 29th Chinese president goes west, is double-crossed (4)

> **XXIX** Def: 29,  XI goes west, Double Crossed XX  ??? In grid as IXXX which caused no end of pain!!!

36 Female concealing Wade's adversary sabotaged copier (5)

> **XEROX** XX -female, ROE vs Wade. (anagram)

37 Horse leaves shadow to send a document (3)

> **FAX**  SHADOWFAX - SHADOW*  (Horse in Lord of the Rings)  Thanks M Oehm!

39 Gas missing nitrogen, with oxidizing second component! (4)

> **NEOX**  NEOn + X

40 Austrian range's last signs of weaponized disease (3)

> **RAX** last of anthRAX.

41 Large single mother associated with a letter (4)

> **MA+XI** XI is a Greek letter. Still don't get the definition entirely.

42 Seconds of extremely internationally essential name service (3)

> **XNS** eXtremely iNternationally eSsential

43 Turn next to nothing to operating system (4)

> **UNIX** U-turn + NIX

44 Sussex English retreat reveals former lovers (4)

> **EXES** Sus**SEX E**nglish  retreat (backwards).

**Down**

1 Typesetting engine either way (5)

> **XETEX** (TEX variant, Palindrome

2 Blow out former sleet audibly (6)

> **EXHALE**  Ex Hail Homophone

3 Drive down the runway, intently leading the charge at the front (4)

> **TAXI** **I**ntently leading (first letter) , **TAX** (charge) at the front

4 International body is formerly epicene (6)

> **UN + IS*+ EX**

5 A man with a smart device (5)

> **ALEX(A*)**

6 Darius and Xander are very small (4)

> **XXXS** (characters from movie xXx)

8 Watch an acting part by an unknown (5)

> **ROLEX** ROLE + X (unknown in algebra)

9 UK resident holds former EU drama (6)

> **BR(EX)IT**

10 Planck and Weber's thousand hatchets (5)

> **M + AXES** (Roman numeral M,  Max Planck, Max Weber.

13 Clutching crucifix, Rachel's sister brings up physicist (5)

> **HA(X)EL**  Rachel's sister was LEAH.

14 The last, not last, third-to-last hair loss medicine (5)

> **FINAX** FINAL -L (not last) + X (third to last letter)

15 Caramel dessert gets back former colour (6)

> **FLA(XE)N**  FLAN + EX(back)

20 Turn around hydra's head, multiply hybrid (6)

> **SP(H)IN +X**

22 Oddly flag user experience as fake (4)

> **FAUX** Oddly FlAg UX

23 Pixar's choppy practical application (6)

> **PRAXIS** (Anagram)

25 Dresden native changes sides for island (5)

> **NAXOS** (Greek Island)  SAXON (changes sides S <--> N)

26 Head-scratching athlete makes a jump (4)

> b**OXER** Horse jump.

27 Essential to fix a robot coming up a compound (5)

> **BORAX**  fiX A ROBot (Since this is a DOWN clue, Coming up is the same as BACK for an across clue)

30 Farm animals are second to none, times square closer north (4)

> **OXEN**  nOne X (times) squarE N

31 Letter closer's winning line (3)

> **XXX**  Kisses at end of letter, Winning line in Tic Tac Toe.

32 Chromosome in the middle of one altered gene part (4)

> **EXON** X in altered ONE

33 Make chromosomes for antibiotic (4)

> **DO + XY** DO (make) XY  Doxycillin.

34 Sound effects getting around primary audio port (4)

> **SF(A)X** Port in Tunisia (a =  primary Audio)

38 Cut back a quintillion times (3)

> **AXE** EXA (10^18) back

NOTES:

> 29 is XXIX, not IXXX which really screwed up the bottom left corner!
>   A bit confused with embrace as X in 18A

Comment: No real benefit to posting the grid.  But it helped solve a few clues.

Comment: Thanks for posting the detailed constructions. For 37, [look here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Middle-earth_animals#Shadowfax). And I think the "single" in 41. belongs to the def and the letter is Greek.

Comment: Still don't get LARGE SINGLE as the def, but the rest makes sense.

Comment: Bit of a [flashback to the 80's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxi_single): `:)`

Comment: Aah.  I was an album junkie.  Didn't buy singles.

Comment: Yeah, embrace is another mistake. Confused it with a false friend... D'oh!

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer

**Across**

3. A penguin's formal attire (3)

> TUX (tuxedo, tux is the mascot of linux : a penguin)

**Down**

34. Sound effects getting around primary audio port (4)

> JACK (jack plug)